# How can I simulate a mouse click/keypress without using a Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, keypress, dllimport, mouseclick-event, user32

Now I am using PostMessage and MouseClick to send the key press to the application. What I want is to send the KeyPress and when key press is finish(KeyUp) then send the Mouse Click.

Code

```
    const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0101;
    const int VK_F1 = 0x70;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process processes = Process.GetProcessById(_processID);
        PostMessage(processes.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F1, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        PostMessage(processes.MainWindowHandle, WM_UP, VK_F1, 0);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
```

This Code work but in a high timer interval only. When i decrease the timer to 100 or lower than this it will be like freezing on the mouse click and don't do anymore keypress. What I want to know is how to make it work correctly in lower timer interval. Or does it have any better Solution to make it done.

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than mucking about with the low level events system, have you considered using the [Accessibility APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/index) (built to support e.g. accessibility tools but just generally better because they work at a more "semantic" level than trying to pretend that you're a keyboard/mouse)?

Comment: The API function for faking input is `SendInput`, but why not use UI Automation?